# How to make Diesel auto-generate models?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using this command to generate schema for Diesel:

```
diesel --database-url postgres://postgres:kZLxttcZSN@127.0.0.1:5432/rhythm \
migration run --config-file="${CURRENT_DIR}"/diesel-rhythm.toml
```

and this is the `diesel.toml` config:

```ini
[print_schema]
file = "src/model/diesel/rhythm/rhythm_schema.rs"

# This will cause only the users and posts tables to be output
filter = { only_tables = ["favorites", "songs", "playlist"] }
```

Is it possible to make Diesel auto-generate the models? The model may look like this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Queryable, Deserialize, Default)]
pub struct Music {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub source_id: String
}
```

Right now I write the models by hand. What should I do to make it generate from the Diesel CLI? I read through the documentation but did not found any useful configuration about this.

Comment: Do you mean generating the `Music` model from the db.table definition?

Comment: yes, that's what I meaning, write the model by handle is boring. @NjugunaMureithi

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for [diesel_cli_ext](https://github.com/abbychau/diesel_cli_ext/blob/master/README.md)

First install diesel_cli_ext:

```
cargo install diesel_cli_ext
```

[Then] you would have to generate your schema file the diesel way if you haven't yet:

```
diesel print-schema > src/schema.rs
```

Finally you have to generate the models file:

```
diesel_ext --model > src/models.rs
```

The models in your schema file would be generated in `src/models.rs` eg:

```
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct Music {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub source_id: String
}
```

Comment: Add -t to generate with the table name, diesel_ext --model -t> src/models.rs

Comment: Is it possible to this the opposite way so that models inside Rust upgrade the database?

Comment: @OliverDixon You would have to write a parser for your rust code. You are possibly looking for something like prisma, which would manage the schema, then you could combine it with diesel to generate rust code.